# The GEM paperclip saved my images in public/system not in app/assets/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I am using the gem PaperClip for upload images to my server , but the images are stored in public/system
I need to change this ubication to app/assets/images

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name,:photo

  validates :name, :presence => true    
  validates :email, :presence => true
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => 
           { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

end
```

I found this tutorial of RailsCasts where these options are declared

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>" },
                  :url  => "/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

validates_attachment_presence :photo
validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
```

Comment: It's saved in public so you can be able to access it. There where it should be. I save mine in rails_root/public/assets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [PaperClip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage) there its stated:

> The files that are assigned as attachments are, by default, placed in
>   the directory specified by the `:path` option to `has_attached_file`. By
>   default, this location is
>   `:rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename`

So you need to specify the `:path` variable of `has_attached_file` to your desired path.

Hope it helps!